# function names as looping variables in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to automate repetitive tasks. I have many functions named as `fun1`, `fun2` and so on. I want to run them in a loop. I.e. have something like
`for (i in 1:N) as.function( paste0("fun",i)`. How to do it?

Reprodex:

```
xx = -5:5; 
plot(xx, dnorm(xx), main = "PDF: norm") 
plot(xx, dpois(xx), main = "PDF: pois") 
plot(xx, dbinom(xx), main = "PDF: binom") 
# 

for (i in c("norm", "pois", "binom")) {
  fun <- as.function(paste0("d",i))
  plot(xx, fun(xx), main = paste0("PDF: ", i))  
}
```

Comment: You can pass the functions directly in the loop i.e. `for (i in c(mean, sd, var)) {
  print(i(1:10))
}
` (I don't get the `fun(xx)` part in your example code, so i provided my own example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getFunction` to obtain the function object from its string name.

```r
> getFunction("dnorm")
#function (x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE) 
#.Call(C_dnorm, x, mean, sd, log)
#<bytecode: 0x7fa2e8bc1730>
#<environment: namespace:stats>
```

This means you can write

```r
for (i in c("norm", "pois", "binom")) {
  fun <- getFunction(paste0("d",i))
  plot(xx, fun(xx), main = paste0("PDF: ", i))  
}
```

Note: `dpois` needs `lambda` parameter, so this code causes an error.  `dbinom` also requires additional parameters.